# How do we decide whether an electron orbital has a non-zero or zero probability of lying inside the nucleus of an hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, probability, orbitals

How do we decide whether an electron orbital has a non-zero or zero probability of lying inside the nucleus of an hydrogen atom? It is mostly from the radial function, as to what I think but how exactly is this determined?

Answer (score 1):

[In this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html) you will see the radial hydrogen wavefunctions. It is **only** the l=0 states, S states, that have a value different than zero at r=0.

[image: radialHwavfunct]

The other angular momentum states get a  very small contribution to the probabilities from r>0 to r=1 fermi ( the charged radius of the proton) as 1 fermi is of order 10^-15meters, and the probability is the square of the wave function.

Nothing happens when they do overlap, because of energy considerations:there is no energy level within the proton to allow for a transition to a different state and the neutron is much heavier than the proton. Anyway, to get there the weak interaction will be needed which is the reason that [electron capture i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture)n nuclei where energy allows it, is very small.

Comment: I think this is the link, you wanted? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hydwf.html#c1 Scroll down for 2p.

Comment: I'm sure if we take the interaction of `e` and `p` into account at subatomic length scales, the I=0 state will also not take kindly to having an electron in the nucleus.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP It is  energy conservation and the quantum numbers that just let the electron be. With an appropriate nucleus for energy one gets electron capture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture

Comment: @Gert I wanted the math. One can see that for l=0 the function is a constant, not zero. The others have a r mutliplying the function.

Answer (score 1):

One calculates the probability that the electron is inside the nucleus by integrating $\psi^*\psi$ over the volume of the nucleus.

For example, the radial part of the hydrogen ground state wavefunction is $\psi=\frac{e^{-\frac{r}{a_0}}}{\sqrt{\pi a_0^3}}$,

so the integral is $\frac{1}{\pi a_0^3}\int_0^b e^{-2r/a_0} 4\pi r^2 dr$.

In the above, $a_0$ is the Bohr radius and $b$ is the proton radius.  The integral is easy enough, but there is a trick that you may like.  Since the proton radius is so small (~1 fm) compared to the Bohr radius (~53000 fm), the exponential term is practically a constant ($\approx 1$) over the entire nucleus, so just ignore it!  In this approximation, the integral evaluates to $\frac{4b^3}{3a_0^3}$, which is a pretty small probability, but is it really non-zero?

One way to look at a probability is how often the event occurs.  If we could perform an experiment to locate the electron once every second, we would find it inside the nucleus once every 5 million years or so.  So, it is safe to say you or I will never see it happen, so the probability is zero *for all practical purposes*.